# Entering USA with a soon-expiring US passport

Tags: usa, us-citizens

My US passport expires 16 days from now. I would like to enter the USA from Germany (which is where I spent the holidays). Will I be able to travel despite the near expiry of my passport?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118073/discussion-on-question-by-rehband-entering-usa-with-a-soon-expiring-us-passport).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Entering the US is no problem at all, at least as far as the passport goes (I have not been following Covid-19 related rules). A passport expiring soon can create problems for visitors (non-citizens/aliens). An *expired* passport can create issues for citizens (not necessarily unsurmountable, depending on the specifics) but not one that's still valid, even for one day, when you reach the border.

In practice, it's always good to have at least a few days of validity left (what if the plane is delayed or rerouted?) but there is no specific validity requirement for citizens.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem if you are able to fly non-stop to the US before the passport expires. But if you have a stop in another country, the short time left on the passport could be a problem.

Comment: @GerardAshton Yes, good point, just one day would also be risky in case of irregular operations, what if the plane is delayed due to bad weather. I will expand on that in the answer.

Comment: @Relaxed I think Gerard is referring to connections where you have to pass immigration as if you plan to stay.  For example, if OP were coming not from Germany but South America, and had to stop in Mexico City, Mexico might not let OP in due to such a short validity left on the passport regardless of a claimed & credible plan to leave the country within hours. I don't know which all countries require that (I think the UK doesn't) but in OP's situation, I'd pay extra for a flight plan omitting planned/diversion-possible layovers that could require passport controls.

Comment: @WBT That's another consideration, yes. The way I looked at it, this Q&A is  primarily about entry conditions in the US, I didn't try to cover every possible details of the journey before that point.

Comment: I recognize that, but OP asked "Will I be able to travel despite the near expiry of my passport?" and the answer really depends on where OP is connecting through. "Yes, no problem at all, at least as far as the passport goes" (as this answer currently opens) is **incorrect** or relies on unstated assumptions like a flight that is planned to be and will necessarily be direct as far as international borders with passport controls are concerned.  @GerardAshton and I think it's important to note that, so we have.

Comment: @WBT The full question is “I would like *to enter* the USA from Germany […]”. I am not saying your points are without merit or uninteresting, I already remarked on that, upvoted Gerard's comment and edited my answer accordingly. I disagree that this small detail makes the answer “incorrect” or that I should or could cover any possible travel route (What about freighters? Overnight transit in Istanbul?) when the question isn't even about flights or transit but only about US immigration.

Comment: Incidentally, note that all main hubs in Europe (including London and Istanbul) allow sterile transit. Canada and Mexico do not but don't have any time before expiry requirements for US citizen (I just checked that through TIMATIC, the Mexican ministry of Foreign Affairs and travel.state.gov). So I am not assuming a non-stop flight, just a reasonsable connection. Obviously, we don't know whether the OP has any other passport, they have no reason to detail that since that's not what the question is about.

Comment: Finally, even if you don't share my interpretation of the question, I don't think there was any ambiguity left in my answer after Gerard's useful comment, as I already wrote explicitely that it was about what happens *when you reach the border* as a citizen.

Comment: ‘Entering the US is no problem at all [for citizens]’ While true, it’s important to keep this in perspective. The entry process into the US is slower and more involved even for citizens of the US than the entry processes for visitors to some other parts of the world. If this is the OP’s first time traveling internationally, they may be surprised due to it actually being a bit more involved to get back into the US than it probably was for them to enter Germany.

Comment: From personal experience crossing the land border several times a year..."Did you know your passport expired 6 months ago? I only noticed because the outside is the old style that hasn't been printed in 10 years.  You should probably get that renewed soon."  We had unknowingly crossed with an expired one without anyone noticing a few times.